# Meteor/MongoDB limiting the result

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to find all documents and publish at most 5 from the results.

Following [this section of the MongoDB doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#limit-the-number-of-documents-to-return), I am trying to do this:

```
Meteor.publish('teams', function () {
  return Teams.find().limit(5);
});
```

Yet, in the server console, I get an exception:

```
Exception from sub teams id Pm6jKL8Sv3FSDSTfM TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'limit'
```

The following works fine:

```
Meteor.publish('teams', function () {
  return Teams.find({}, {limit:5});
});
```

Why does the second way work, rather than the first? And where can I find documentation for it?

Comment: are you sure a meteor collection is the mongodb one? meteor not declare that they use mongodb.

Comment: @JiangYD Doesn't Meteor use mongodb? I assumed that I could use mongo API because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor's [collection API](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection) is somewhat different from that of the mongo API. [find](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) takes up to two parameters: a `selector` object, and an `options` object. `options` allows you to specify such things as `sort`, `skip`, `limit` and `fields`, in addition to the meteor-specific `reactive` and `transform`.